# How can I add to LSF Platform new users?

Tags: centos, cluster-computing, hpc, lsf

I scourged the web and the manual for the simple answer this question needs.

If I create new users on my cluster, and if I check 'busers all', they don't appear. Thus, they cannot use 'bjobs', 'bhosts', etc...

A little help would be so nice!

Cheers,

--Max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All users on your system can use LSF. As long as they have loaded LSF in their profile. I usually run these commands so that everybody loads LSF on logon:

1. cd /etc/profile.d
2. ln -s $LSF_CONFDIR/profile.lsf lsf.sh
3. ln -s $LSF_CONFDIR/cshrc.lsf lsf.csh

This loads LSF paths and binaries in your profile, i.e you can run lsid, bsub, bjobs, etc without having to specify the path.

I have never personally used busers but that command is related to lsb.users. In that file you define users and groups that you want to use inside lsb.queues for your queue definitions, e.g. you want a certain queue to be available only for a certain group.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was really stuck there! You made my day.

Comment: It does not work unfortunately... My user's jobs are always pending with :

`PENDING REASONS:
The queue's pre-exec command exited with non-zero status;`

Comment: actually the temp and scratch directory were not writable by my user. PERFECT NOW!!